# Basic fun with static const integral members

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Consider following code:

```
struct X {
  static const int i = 45;
};

void foo() {
  const int* k = &X::i;
}

int main() {
}
```

Without opening your favorite compiler, what would you think would be the result of an attempt on compiling and linking this simple beast?

Some might be surprised that it is going to depend not only on the compiler, but on its optimization options! For instance, on gcc the code will refuse to link with optimization turned off, but will gladly link (and produce runnable-doing-nothing executable) with any optimization turned on.

The diagnostics in the failure case would be funny - symbol `X::i` would not be found. Optimization-enabled links will succeed, because `X::i` will be thrown away.

And question. Is it correct behaviour of the compiler to *compile* this code? Since `X::i` does not have a linkage, should not compiler complain when asked to produce a code which asks for a linkage on this symbol?

Comment: You are odr-using `i` so it has to be defined, it is  no diagnostic required if you don't

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I don't see anything missing from the comment for it to be an answer?

Comment: @curiousguy I think the odr tag is better, it is surely more readable. I voted to make that one a synonym of the odr tag. Although it is not as old, odd I never noticed that one before.

Comment: There is no correct behaviour for code that has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @M.M NDR and UB are not exactly the same, NDR is if I understand correctly is generally for compile time issue while UB is for run-time issues.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour there's ill-formed NDR, and UB (which is implicitly NDR).  If the program is ill-formed then the compiler does not have to generate an executable; and if it does then the behaviour of such an executable is undefined.

Comment: @M.M like I said in another comment, I do not see any benefit of this defined in the standard the way it is defined.

Comment: @SergeyA it's difficult for compilers to detect, especially since compilation and linking are normally done by two separate programs. To diagnose this would need a change in object file format to make a note that there were variables in the source whose access has been optimized out, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are [odr-using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) `i` by taking its address it has to be defined outside the class:

```
const int X::i ;
```

Violations of this rule fall into the *no diagnostic required* category, so this is completely valid behavior:

> Informally, an object is odr-used if its address is taken, or a
>   reference is bound to it, and a function is odr-used if a function
>   call to it is made or its address is taken. If an object or a function
>   is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; a
>   violation of that is a link-time error.

This can depend on the compiler, the optimizations level etc...

Draft C++ standard  section `3.2` [basic.def.odr] says:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic
>   required

Some notes:

- Catching odr violations in general is a [hard problem](http://hubicka.blogspot.com/search/label/devirtualization).
- In this case, catching it is not as simple as it looks since `i` could be defined later on or in another translation unit.
- We want out of line definitions since we only want one definition, while the declarations can be repeated i.e. if they are part of a header file.

Comment: I believe, in this case it would not be much to ask for at least a warning? This has an unplesant effect of breaking debug builds while succeeding in releases, and of course, on a much bigger codebase... But this answers my question, thanks.

Comment: I understand it is hard in general case. But in this particular case I see nothing hard. Compiler knows very well that I shouldn't take an address of static const i.

Comment: @SergeyA it could be defined later on or in another translation unit.

Comment: Didn't realize that you can still define the X::i as a symbol. I do not think this particular aspect of C++ is helpful to developers.

Comment: @SergeyA this is why you learn from books , and not trial-and-error

Comment: @M.M feel obliged to say, unlike most of the developers, I have masters in Computer Sciences. Can calim the same about you? Yet sometimes I have to support the code written by other not so-academically-acclaimed developers, and the less surprises I see there, the better. I appreciate when compiler can help me out there, and I bitch when it does not.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, this is correct. Still, I would rather say, it would be nice if defining non-linkage symbol (static extern integral) would be made an error. Than any attempt to use it would be an error too. I can't see a benefit of allowing such symbol to be defined as a linkage-having symbol.

Comment: @SergeyA you might be surprised who has what qualifications and experience. Anyway, definitions of static member variables is a basic part of C++ , so I'm not sure what point you are trying to make by saying that you managed to get a master's degree whilst only learning bits and pieces of C++  . I'm sure there are many people who learnt other languages entirely,etc.

Comment: @M.MM, i hoped i am clear enough. Apparently I am not. Anyways, let's leave at at this.